# OpenCV undistort() function with newCameraMatrix

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix, computer-vision, camera-calibration

I calibrated a wide angle camera (~120° horizontal, ~110° vertical) using the Pinhole camera model. The result is quite good but large areas of the image are discarded.

[image: good]

So I'm trying to use the getOptimalNewCameraMatrix function (using alpha = 1) to calculate the newCameraMatrix and then pass it to cv::undistord, but the resulting frame is really distorted.

[image: bad]

The code I use is:

```
// Matrices calculation
data.rms = calibrateCamera(objectPoints, imagePoints, data.size, data.cameraMatrix,
    data.distCoeffs, data.rvecs, data.tvecs, settings.calibFlags);

if(!settings.cropCorrected) {
    Rect roi;
    data.newCameraMatrix = getOptimalNewCameraMatrix(data.cameraMatrix, data.distCoeffs, 
    data.size, 1, data.size, &roi, true);
}

// Undistort
cv::undistort(in, corrected, cameraMatrix, distCoeffs, newCameraMatrix);
```

This is simple but there is something not working. I have already tried to use roi to crop the inner area, in the hope that it would have been anyway bigger than without the additional matrix, but in fact it's not.

How can i resolve the situation?

Comment: Hard to help without original images, calibrated parameter values. The pixelated circle you observe in the corrected image is due to a singularity in the undistortion function. As there appear to be valid pixels beyond it, you may be using an invalid model, or inaccurate calibration parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out. The problem is that alpha = 1.0 is simply too big. Curiously even using 0.0 the newCameraMatrix enlarges by ~20° the fields of view and apparently no wrong pixels or distortion are present.

Comment: Hi, I got the same problem. I tried to set alpha=0.5 or 0.0 but it didn't solve the problem. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59538424/opencv-undistortion-image-with-a-strange-circle